# React-Native : Can react native find out the exact absolute position for each device?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, imagebackground

I want to show text on image using absolute position.
However, it is difficult to determine the exact position because the screen size is different for each device.

Is there a way to calculate the exact position?

I posted a similar question, but I didn't get the answer I wanted.
[my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449242/how-should-i-handle-the-absolute-position-when-the-screen-size-is-different/65449301?noredirect=1#comment115712421_65449301)

[image]

Below is the code I've tried.

```
 <ImageBackground
      source={require("../../assets/brain/ohi.png")}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "relative" }}
      resizeMode="contain"
      onLayout={(event) => this.setLayout(event.nativeEvent.layout)}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: windowWidth * 0.22,
          top: windowHeight * 0.4,
        }}
      >
        Text_1
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 280,
          top: 300,
        }}
      >
        Text_2
      </Text>
    </ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203154/get-size-of-a-view-in-react-native).

Note that the `x` and `y` coordinates of the `layout` object are relative to the immediate parent component of the component where `onLayout` is used. In your case, `ImageBackground`'s layout is taken relative to whatever immediately wraps it.

A possible solution to place `Text` like so is a composition tree such as

```js
const [layout, setLayout] = useState();

<View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
  <Image width={200} height={200} onLayout={event => setLayout(event.nativeEvent.layout)} />
  
  <Text style={{position: 'absolute', top: (layout?.y || 20) + 20, left: (layout?.x || 30) + 30}} />
</View>
```